# -bash: /Users/username/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate: Permission denied

Tags: python, macos, bash, shell

i start to install Enthought Canopy on my mac to learn it. However,
when i fire a new terminal, there will be one message at the top of my terminal it says:

```
-bash: /Users/username/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate: Permission denied
```

What's wrong with this? Why this command is executed automatically?

If this question is off topic, i am really sorry for this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I have to use `sudo ls -l` command to check the file's permission. When i try to find which folder cause this problem, it seems i cannot use `ls -l /Users/username/Library` for normal user, i have to use `sudo` for this. I tried to `sudo chmod 755 /Users/username/Library` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The file you're trying to execute, has executing permissions?

Comment: Do you have permissions to access this file?

Comment: i use `sudo ls -l` the file, the permissions are `-rwxrwxrwx`. but i cannot use `ls -l` directly.

Comment: When you execute ls -l directly, what do you see? It is possible that the file you are looking at has the permission, but the directory that it is contained in does not have permission to allow you to go into it.

Comment: try 'find . -name activate' from your username directory. It will show which directories you cannot get in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like one of the directories in the hierarchy above the file that you are looking for does not have the permission set for you to enter it (as yourself).

Check the entire hierarchy to see what the permissions are.

```
 /Users/username/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/
```

Did you install it as yourself or as root (sudo)? You may have to change the owner and group of the installed files or directories.

From username run

```
find . -name activate
```

This will show which directories cannot be reached.

Comment: i don't think i use sudo to install this. also i checked the hierarchy, all the folders there is rwx for the owner.

Comment: @Chancy In a comment below you said you did not run it manually, how did you run it. Also did you check the owners and group names of all the subdirectories?

Comment: When i start a new terminal, this error message come out below `Last login: Wed Feb 26 11:24:30 on ttys008`

Comment: @Chancy that is not an error, it is an informative message. What was the result of the find command?

Comment: the result is `./Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/bin/activate
./Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
find: ./Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.flashplayer.installmanager.savedState: Permission denied`

Comment: @Chancy what does "which activate" show. what happens if you try to run it with the full path name?

Answer (score -1):

did you try run this command with root?

Log with root: sudo su -
Or: su - root

After that, run the command again.

Comment: I didn't run this command manually... i also want to know why this command are executed...